# SQL: count and show all rows and columns of all tables under a scheme

Tags: sql, size, dimensions

somewhere on the net (source missing, may be here) I got this SQL-statement:

```
SELECT t.NAME AS TableName, SUM(a.total_pages) * 8 AS TotalSpaceKB, p.Rows FROM sys.tables t 
INNER JOIN sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id 
INNER JOIN sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id 
INNER JOIN sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id 
WHERE t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' AND t.NAME LIKE '%MY_TABLES%' AND s.Name LIKE 'MY_ACHEMA'
  AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
  AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255
GROUP BY t.Name, p.Rows
ORDER BY p.Rows DESC
```

which gives me a beautiful view with 3 columns. something like this:

```
           TableName  TotalSpaceKB     Rows
               TABLE       3231656    76000
               TABLE       2305632    29136
               TABLE       2213128    14160
               TABLE       1954200     3020
etc...
```

now I'd like to expand it to inclide the number of columns of each table. How can this be done?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the grouping and used subqueries:

```
SELECT
    t.NAME AS TableName,
    (SELECT SUM(a.total_pages) * 8 
        FROM sys.indexes i
        INNER JOIN sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id 
        INNER JOIN sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id 
        WHERE t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255
    ) AS TotalSpaceKB,
    (SELECT SUM(p.Rows)
        FROM sys.indexes i
        INNER JOIN sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id 
        WHERE t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255
    ) AS Rows,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.columns c WHERE t.OBJECT_ID = c.object_id) AS Columns
FROM sys.tables t 
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id 
WHERE t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' AND t.NAME LIKE '%MY_TABLES%' AND s.Name LIKE 'MY_ACHEMA'
  AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
ORDER BY Rows DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you by adding in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.

```
SELECT t.NAME AS TableName, SUM(a.total_pages) * 8 AS TotalSpaceKB, p.Rows, COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) AS ColumnCount
FROM sys.tables t 
INNER JOIN sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id 
INNER JOIN sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id 
INNER JOIN sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id 
LEFT JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id 
LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS ISC ON t.NAME = ISC.TABLE_NAME 
WHERE t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' AND t.NAME LIKE '%MY_TABLES%' AND s.Name LIKE 'MY_ACHEMA'
  AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
  AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255
GROUP BY t.Name, p.Rows
ORDER BY p.Rows DESC
```

Comment: almost right! there is something strange happening, this doubles the amount of columns for some table, but not for others! am I also calculating double as much rows?